# Creating an analytic expression for a recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, summation, recurrence-relations, recursion

I am trying to solve the following problem:

A sequence is defined as follows:  $a_0$ = -1, $a_1$ = 0 and $a_{n+1}$ = $a_n^{2} - (n+1)^{2} * a_{n-1} - 1$

I know that there are methods for solving recurrence involving transforming things to a sum of geometric series, or product of some sorts. Another method I tried was solving for the characteristic Root Equation, but this problem is different since we have a squared term for $a_n$. Any insights, tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In this case guessing the formula and proving it afterwards works just fine. We have the sequence
$$
-1,0,3,8,15,24,35,48,\dots
$$
That looks like one less than a perfect squares, so we can expect
$$
a_n=n^2-1.
$$
Check on initial values and substituting to the recurrence proves it is correct.

Sometimes [oeis.org](https://oeis.org/) can help as well, this sequence would be found under [A005563](https://oeis.org/A005563). After applying the proper offset you would get the same formula.